# How to think about gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Hellow, i'v just started vector calc and sorry, but $f^{'\vec{u}}(x,y)=\mid{\nabla{f(x,y)}}\mid{}\cdot{}cos(\theta)$ seems like a bs... to me. because it too easy or so

why is a plane tangent to a surface?

why is there always a dir gradient equal to $0$? etc.

Have you had similar naive concerns?

Comment: This post would profit if you clarified the notation. What is $\theta$? What planes are you talking about? Also your reason for posting isn't very clear.

Comment: @ラミタ that angle in a dot product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does $f'_u(x,y)=\nabla f(x,y) \cdot u$ seem like such a bs to you? It all has to do with the definition of the directional derivative along $v$ and chain rule. Say you have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We define the directional derivative at a point $p$ as the derivative of $f$ composed with the regular parametrization, by arclength, $\lambda:(-\epsilon ,\epsilon) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, for some real number $\epsilon$, given by $\lambda(s)=p+s\cdot v$, for some vector $v$.  All this mumbo-jumbo means the following. 
Take a point p and trace a small rectilinear path in the direction of v. Now consider how your function changes when restricted to that path, along that path. What is its rate of change at p? Well, the chain rule answers our question: $$\frac{d}{ds}f(\lambda(0))=df(p)\cdot \frac{d\lambda}{ds}(0)$$
Where $df(p)$ is the differential of $f$ at $p$, defined by $$df(p)=\sum_{i=i}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i$$
This differential is essentialy the derivative of f at p. Now, there is an isomorphism (a one to one correspondence) between the differential and a certain vector, induced by the inner product. This is a fancy way of saying that $df(p)\cdot \frac{d\lambda(s)}{ds}$ gives the same result as dotting that certain vector with the derivative of $\lambda$. We call that certain vector the **gradient** of $f$ at $p$, and so we can write $$df(p)\cdot \frac{d\lambda(s)}{ds}=\left \langle \nabla f(p),\frac{d\lambda(s)}{ds} \right \rangle$$
Because the parametrization is by arclength, $|\frac{d\lambda(s)}{ds}|=1$, and so, $$\left \langle \nabla f(p),\frac{d\lambda(s)}{ds} \right \rangle=|\nabla f(p)|\cos(\theta)$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the gradient at p and the derivative of $\lambda$ at p. So, you see, nothing about this is "easy", we just throw all these definitions under the carpet and define the directional derivative straight as the gradient dotted with the vector. In fact, the more cumbersome definition given above is the natural way to define such a derivative.
Now, onto your other questions. 
Why is a plane tangent to a surface? Well, not every plane is tangent to a surface at every point. In general, a surface's point will admit one plane that is tangent to it, but it might admit other structures that are tangent to it. I'm not entirely sure of what is meant by that question. 
About your last question, it isn't true that there is always a point at which the gradient is null. For that to happen, each and every one of the partial derivatives of f has to be 0.

Comment: thank you for your response! for now, would it work for a second derivative? ?? i think no! and suppose thats what confused me? also your answer uses concepts that I don't understand - can you hint me what $\lambda$ is? about the last question i meant that *directional *derivative is zero when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. so it is just defined that way.

Comment: $\lambda$ is just the parametrization of a small rectilinear path. Haven't you been taught that in Calculus yet? It is essentially a function that given some parameter outputs a path in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: There is an analogue to the second directional derivative. It is essentially the directional derivative **of the directional derivative** You can arrive at an expression for it by differentiating $\frac{d}{ds}f(λ(0))=$ again. I'll let you try and work it out.

Comment: About your last question, yes there is always a direction where the directional derivative is zero. You can think about those vectors conceptually as the directions where the function locally isn't changing. In other words, those vectors lie tangent to the curves of constant value of the function. Conversely, because the gradient is perpendicular to those vectors, the gradient is always perpendicular to those curves